# Why am I getting a date format error in 1 entity?

Tags: datetime, error-handling, sap-gateway

So I have a SAP Gateway server with some entities that are sent to the client side on request. All the entities currently only have `getEntitySet` redefined, and everything works fine except in 1 entity.

One of the entities, when I try to do `getEntitySet`, returns this error that refers to the date fields in it:

> In the context of data services an unknown internal server error occurred

In the error log it says:

> Invalid format(return table): Row number 1, Property name 'XXXX', Property value '04.10.15'

In the rest of the entities, everything works fine.

I tried:

- using different dates
- putting dates with different formats in the fields
- deleting the date fields from said entity and returning them
- setting the date fields as nullable
- deleting the whole entity and creating it again
- created a new entity with only date fields, it had the same error

Nothing is working, 3 people tried to help me, but no one knows what's the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to help if you mix create entity and get entity in your question. Concerning the get problem, it seems that the date format is incorrect in the database and when it tries to return it, the value `04.10.15` is clearly not a valid date. What exact value is in the database? What date is returned for an entity okay, and what value is in the database? (please indicate the exact XML or JSON value)

Comment: The date in the database is the same as the other dates- it's all in the format of 'YYYYmmDD'. When I do the select in the getEntitySet, it selects the date just fine, but somewhere between the end of the getEntitySet method and the client it fails.  

I tried during debug to change the date in the 'bad' entity to a date from a 'good' entity, and in the entityset it looked ok, but after the getEntitySet, on the way to the client side, it failed with the same error. (Everything happens the same way whether I trigger the getEntitySet from the actual client side of from the Gateway Client.)

Comment: In short, there is no difference between the 'bad' entity and the rest of the entities- same type of date fields both in the entity and the database, same process in getEntitySet. Only in the 'bsd' entity, after the method, for some reason it tries to convert the date to 'DD.mm.YY' instead of 'DD.mm.YYYY'.

Comment: So, you say it's not reproducible, and you're not able to find the issue. I think we can't do better. You should look at SAP support Knowledge Base, and if you find nothing contact the support.

Answer (score 0):

The date format you passed is uncorrect

```
20220107
```

The above is how date variable are read, no period, starts with year.

Hope that helps